# How to test non-exported typescript functions with jest without emitting js files

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have some non-exported functions I want to test in jest.  In JavaScript, I'd use [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire).  In order to test TypeScript using rewire, you point your `rewire()` call at the emitted JavaScript file rather than the TypeScript file.

However, I'm using webpack to compile my TS, so in my tsconfig.json, I have `{ compilerOptions: { noEmit: true } }`, and there is no emitted file to point rewire at.

How can I test my non-exported functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a less-than-ideal but better-than-exporting workaround.

**jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  globals: {
    TEST: true,
    // ...
  }
};
```

**global.d.ts**

```ts
export {};
declare global {
  const TEST: boolean;
  // ...
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const { DefinePlugin } = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({ TEST: 'false' })
  ]
};
```

**my-module.ts**

```ts
function myNonExportedFunction() {
  // ...
}

if (TEST) {
  module.exports.myNonExportedFunction = myNonExportedFunction;
}
```

**__tests__/module.ts**

```ts
const { myNonExportedFunction } = require('../my-module');

test('myNonExportedFunction', () => {
  // ...
});
```

The two drawbacks to this method are:

1. you're including minimal test code in your production code (though webpack can remove code based on constants)
2. you lose strong typing on your non-exported functions, though you lose that type-safety with rewire anyway